# Real system wide proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

Is it possible to configure something (in one place) that directs all http and https traffic through a specific proxy.

At work we need to go through a proxy to get to the outside world. That proxy address needs to configured into a lot of applications. Here is some of the places:

- System Settings (Which should be system wide, but only applies to browsers)
- Spotify
- IntelliJ
- Maven
- /etc/environment

At home there is no proxy and I would like to easily disable proxy. It is a lot of work changing the configuration of all the applications each time  you change location.

Can you intercept traffic and redirect it through a local proxy which then can be configured to forward to the proxy or just go directly to the requested address?

Comment: If you use System Settings and apply system-wide, changes are made to `/etc/environment`. It's up to the rest of the apps to honour `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`, etc. Most standard Ubuntu programs do. If Spottify or Maven doesn't, it's on them. That said, you could always run `squid` yourself, so the programs are always using your localhost proxy, and squid configuration handles whether a real proxy is being used or not. That's what I used to do.

Comment: @muru Could you provide an answer on how to configure squid :)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup this

```
vi /etc/environment
```

append these lines

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
https_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

and after that

```
source /etc/environment
```

and for installation of packages etc...via apt-get
Create a file called 95proxies in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, and include the following:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
```

Comment: I did this but still need to configure each individual application.

Comment: You don't have to. These are system wide settings. You can specify even JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment. Once you specify JAVA_HOME in that and follow the steps that i mentioned. Maven, Gradle and everybody start considering JAVA_HOME mentioned out there.

Comment: I've encountered instances where Maven still ignored the `http_proxy` in `/etc/environment`. Maven was only able to fetch after I added `~/.m2/settings.xml`.